# Finding blank regions in image

Tags: python, language-agnostic, image-processing, numpy, python-imaging-library

This question is somewhat language-agnostic, but my tool of choice happens to be a numpy array.

What I am doing is taking the difference of two images via PIL:

```
img = ImageChops.difference(img1, img2)
```

And I want to find the rectangular regions that contain changes from one picture to another. Of course there's the built in `.getbbox()` method, but if there are two regions with changes it will return a box from one region to another, and if there are only 1 pixel changes in each corner it will return the whole image.

For instance consider the following where `o` is a non-zero pixel:

```
______________________
|o            ooo    |
|      oooo   ooo    |
|      o             |
|      o  o          |
|                    |
|     oo       o     |
|    o  o     ooo    |
|     oo     ooooo   |
|             ooo    |
|              o     |
|____________________|
```

I'd like to get 4x4-tuples containing the bounding boxes for each non-zero region. For the edge case of the

```
oooo
o
o  o
```

structure, I'm not terribly worried how that's handled - either getting both sections separately or together, because the bounds of the inverted-L shape will completely overlap the bounds of the single pixel.

I've never done anything this advanced with image processing so I wanted to get some input before I really write anything (and if there are pre-existing methods in the modules I'm already using, I welcome them!).

My psuedocode-ish version goes something like this:

```
for line in image:
   started = False
   for pixel in line:
      if pixel and not started:
         started = True
         save start coords
      elif started and not pixel:
         started = False
         save end coords (x - 1 of course)
```

This should give me a list of coordinates, but then I have to determine if the regions are contiguous. I could do that with a graph-type search? (We did plenty of DFS and BFS in Algorithms last semester) Of course I guess I could do that instead/in conjunction with my previous loops?

I won't be doing this on "large" images - they're pulled from a webcam and the best one I currently have does 640x480. At most I'd be doing 720p or 1080p, but that's far enough into the future that it's not a real concern.

So my question(s): Am I headed on the right path, or am I way off? And more important, are there any built-in functions that prevent me from re-inventing the wheel? And finally, are there any good resources I should look at (tutorials, papers, etc.) that will help out here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe [scipy's ndimage module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html) has everything you need...

Here's a quick example

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.ndimage.morphology

# The array you gave above
data = np.array( 
        [
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        ])


# Fill holes to make sure we get nice clusters
filled = sp.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes(data)

# Now seperate each group of contigous ones into a distinct value
# This will be an array of values from 1 - num_objects, with zeros
# outside of any contigous object
objects, num_objects = sp.ndimage.label(filled)

# Now return a list of slices around each object
#  (This is effectively the tuple that you wanted)
object_slices =  sp.ndimage.find_objects(objects)

# Just to illustrate using the object_slices
for obj_slice in object_slices:
    print data[obj_slice]
```

This outputs:

```
[[1]]
[[1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]]
[[1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1]]
[[1]]
[[0 1 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0]]
[[0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]]
```

Note that the "object_slices" are basically what you originally asked for, if you need the actual indicies.

Edit: Just wanted to point out that despite it appearing to properly handle the edge case of

```
[[1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1]]
```

it actually doesn't (Thus the extra lone [[1]]).  You can see this if you print out the "objects" array and take a look at objects 3 & 4.

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 6 6 6 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 6 6 6 6 6 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 6 6 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Hope that helps!

[[1](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html)]

Comment: Holy smokes that's perfect! That's exactly what I wanted - and I think I actually prefer it to handle the edge case that way - that way it really will get the boxes for *all* the pixels. I wish I could up vote more than once!

Comment: @Wayne - Glad to help!  There's quite a nice batch of functions in scipy.ndimage, once you learn how to string the various operators together.  Good luck!

Comment: @JoeKington is one of the most helpful programmers out there

Comment: I know this is wrong `data[np.where(max(np.sum(obj_slice))]` .. But is there a way I can print just the largest object?

Comment: @chimpsarehungry - By "largest", do you mean the one that covers the largest area? If so, just sort the `object_slices` list by the product of the size of the slices. E.g. have a look a the last few lines here: https://gist.github.com/joferkington/5074650#file-gistfile1-py

Comment: Thanks Joe that works. Yeah I meant largest area. I don't see a scipy measurement for circularity of an object. Do you know of any ways to get roundness (0 = line, 1 = perfect circle)?

Comment: circularity = 4pi(area/perimeter^2) ... Well all I would need is an algorithm for perimeter.

Comment: This seems to work: `np.sum(mahotas.labeled.bwperim(object, n=8)*object)`

Comment: @chimpsarehungry - Mahotas is quite a handy library!  Alternatively, as a circularity measurement, you could use the ratio of the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix. (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005659/compute-eigenvectors-of-image-in-python/9007249#9007249 )  For small images (or slices of images) the first example in that answer is plenty fast enough. Using the moments of the image is only necessary if it's a large image (or large slice).  At any rate, the two measurements (perimeter vs. eigenvalues) measure different things, so which is "better" depends entirely on your data.

Comment: Sorry I'm not seeing how that example applies. Say I have my hundreds of eigenvalues for the covariance matrix for my image..what ratio am I looking for as a measure of circularity?

Answer (score 1):

You could look for connected components in the image and then determine the bounding boxes of these components.

Comment: I'm confused - how is this different than what I said I was doing?

Answer (score 1):

A clustering package ([ie this](http://python-cluster.sourceforge.net/)) should be able to most of the work ( find connected pixels ). Finding the bounding box for a cluster is trivial then.

Comment: How would clustering help (this package especially)? From what I gather reading the docstrings, it can only find data that are X distance away, and doesn't (seem) to store any X-Y data. Am I missing something?