# Calculating and Plotting 2nd moment of image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I am trying to plot the 2nd moments onto a image file (the image file is a numpy array for brightness distribution). I have a rough understanding that 2nd moment is sort of like moment of inertia (Ixx,Iyy) which is a tensor but I am not too sure how to calculate it and how it would translate into two intersecting lines with the centroid at its intersection. I tried using [scipy.stats.mstats.moment](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.moment.html) but I am unsure what to put as axis if I just want two 2nd moments that intersects at centroid.

Also it returns an array but I am not exactly sure what the values in the array signify, and how that relate to what I am going to plot (because the scatter method in the plotting module takes in at least 2 corresponding values in order to be plotted) ?

Thank you.

Comment: Not to plug one of my own answers, but see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005659/compute-eigenvectors-of-image-in-python/9007249#9007249  Basically, `scipy.stats.moment` expects x,y,z coordinates. You can easily pass in an array of i,j,z (where i,j are the row, column coords and z is the brightness - See the first example in the linked question), but this is computationally inefficient for a regularly-gridded image.  For regularly-gridded images, you can make a few shortcuts that will speed things up for large images.

Comment: @JoeKington I tried calculating moments about x,y and then plotting them, but the plot seems completely irrelavant to the image in my brightness distribution  'x_moment =stats.moment(data, moment=2,axis=0) ; y_moment =stats.moment(data, moment=2,axis=1) ;import matplotlib.pyplot as plt ;img_plot = ;plt.imshow(data,cmap=cm.gray, norm = log_norm,origin="lower") ;for yindex,yvalue in np.ndenumerate(y_moment): ;for xindex, xvalue in np.ndenumerate(x_moment): ;plt.scatter(yvalue,xvalue, c='r', s=10) plt.show() `