# How to detect a black lake on a white snowy background in an aerial image?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, simplecv

Here is a sample aerial image:
![aerial image of some unfrozen lakes][1]

How do I automatically detect and extract parameters of the black unfrozen lake from the image? I'm primarily using Python.

EDIT: see my answer below; I think I've found the solution.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310681/finding-blank-regions-in-image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the quick way to do it in SimpleCV:

```
from SimpleCV import *

lakeimg = Image('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku8F8.jpg') #load this image from web, or could be locally if you wanted.
invimg = lakeimg.invert() #we invert because blobs looks for white blobs, not black
lakes = invimg.findBlobs() # you can always change parameters to find different sized blobs
if lakes: lakes.draw() #if it finds blobs then draw around them
invimg.show() #display the image
```

If you wanted you can always play with parameters, typically we use ratios to image size if you wanted it to be fairly robust.  There are also a bunch of options in the Features class for drawing bounding boxes on a few blobs, etc.

Comment: Wow, I was having trouble with findBlobs because I didn't know it looked for white blobs! So, how do I go through each blob and mess around with the data such as number of pixels in the blob, bounding box, centroid?

Comment: Nevermind, I've got the blob manipulation figured out. http://simplecv.org/docs/SimpleCV.Features.html#i/SimpleCV.Features.Blob.Blob

Answer (score 2):

This is an image segmentation problem, and there are in general lots of different ways you could go about it. The easiest way here would seem to be region growing:

- Find every pixel whose grey value is lower than some threshold you pick to separate black from white - these pixels are your 'seeds'.
- Flood out from them, using the grow condition that you only flood into pixels whose grey value is also below a certain threshold (possibly the same one as before, but could be different). Terminate when you can't grow the regions you have any further. During the flooding process, combine seeds that are reachable from each other into the same region. This process will produce a number of connected regions. You can keep track of the sizes of these regions during the flooding process.
- Remove any regions that are below a certain size (alternatively, if you are only interested in the largest lake, pick the largest region you have).
- Calculate the parameters you want from the pixels that are part of the lake(s). For example, the mean grey value of a lake would be the mean of the grey values of the pixels in the lake, etc. Different techniques will be needed for different parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I've got it using the following:

```
###Credits:
###http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525313/rectangular-bounding-box-around-blobs-in-a-monochrome-image-using-python
###http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087919/how-can-i-improve-my-paw-detection

import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
import scipy.spatial as spatial
import scipy.misc as misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

class BBox(object):
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        '''
        (x1, y1) is the upper left corner,
        (x2, y2) is the lower right corner,
        with (0, 0) being in the upper left corner.
        '''
        if x1 > x2: x1, x2 = x2, x1
        if y1 > y2: y1, y2 = y2, y1
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
    def taxicab_diagonal(self):
        '''
        Return the taxicab distance from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2)
        '''
        return self.x2 - self.x1 + self.y2 - self.y1
    def overlaps(self, other):
        '''
        Return True iff self and other overlap.
        '''
        return not ((self.x1 > other.x2)
                    or (self.x2 < other.x1)
                    or (self.y1 > other.y2)
                    or (self.y2 < other.y1))
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.x1 == other.x1
                and self.y1 == other.y1
                and self.x2 == other.x2
                and self.y2 == other.y2)

def find_paws(data, smooth_radius = 5, threshold = 0.0001):
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087919/how-can-i-improve-my-paw-detection
    """Detects and isolates contiguous regions in the input array"""
    # Blur the input data a bit so the paws have a continous footprint 
    data = ndimage.uniform_filter(data, smooth_radius)
    # Threshold the blurred data (this needs to be a bit > 0 due to the blur)
    thresh = data > threshold
    # Fill any interior holes in the paws to get cleaner regions...
    filled = ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes(thresh)
    # Label each contiguous paw
    coded_paws, num_paws = ndimage.label(filled)
    # Isolate the extent of each paw
    # find_objects returns a list of 2-tuples: (slice(...), slice(...))
    # which represents a rectangular box around the object
    data_slices = ndimage.find_objects(coded_paws)
    return data_slices

def slice_to_bbox(slices):
    for s in slices:
        dy, dx = s[:2]
        yield BBox(dx.start, dy.start, dx.stop+1, dy.stop+1)

def remove_overlaps(bboxes):
    '''
    Return a set of BBoxes which contain the given BBoxes.
    When two BBoxes overlap, replace both with the minimal BBox that contains both.
    '''
    # list upper left and lower right corners of the Bboxes
    corners = []

    # list upper left corners of the Bboxes
    ulcorners = []

    # dict mapping corners to Bboxes.
    bbox_map = {}

    for bbox in bboxes:
        ul = (bbox.x1, bbox.y1)
        lr = (bbox.x2, bbox.y2)
        bbox_map[ul] = bbox
        bbox_map[lr] = bbox
        ulcorners.append(ul)
        corners.append(ul)
        corners.append(lr)        

    # Use a KDTree so we can find corners that are nearby efficiently.
    tree = spatial.KDTree(corners)
    new_corners = []
    for corner in ulcorners:
        bbox = bbox_map[corner]
        # Find all points which are within a taxicab distance of corner
        indices = tree.query_ball_point(
            corner, bbox_map[corner].taxicab_diagonal(), p = 1)
        for near_corner in tree.data[indices]:
            near_bbox = bbox_map[tuple(near_corner)]
            if bbox != near_bbox and bbox.overlaps(near_bbox):
                # Expand both bboxes.
                # Since we mutate the bbox, all references to this bbox in
                # bbox_map are updated simultaneously.
                bbox.x1 = near_bbox.x1 = min(bbox.x1, near_bbox.x1)
                bbox.y1 = near_bbox.y1 = min(bbox.y1, near_bbox.y1) 
                bbox.x2 = near_bbox.x2 = max(bbox.x2, near_bbox.x2)
                bbox.y2 = near_bbox.y2 = max(bbox.y2, near_bbox.y2) 
    return set(bbox_map.values())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    data = misc.imread('sampleKiteLakeImage.jpg')
    im = ax.imshow(data)    
    data_slices = find_paws(255-data, smooth_radius = 2, threshold = 200)

    bboxes = slice_to_bbox(data_slices) #remove_overlaps(slice_to_bbox(data_slices))
    for bbox in bboxes:
        xwidth = bbox.x2 - bbox.x1
        ywidth = bbox.y2 - bbox.y1
        p = patches.Rectangle((bbox.x1, bbox.y1), xwidth, ywidth,
                              fc = 'none', ec = 'red')
        ax.add_patch(p)

    plt.show()
```

Here is the final image with overlapping boxes.
[image: boxes outlining lakes with no overlap]

Make

```
bboxes = slice_to_bbox(data_slices) #remove_overlaps(slice_to_bbox(data_slices))
```

into

```
bboxes = remove_overlaps(slice_to_bbox(data_slices))
```

to get rid of overlaps:
[image: boxes outlining lakes with overlap]

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, you can create an array of the areas where the brightness is below your threshold ([0,1] array).  There are some methods to count the number/size, etc. of the shapes, such as recursive deletion.